# How to use push_back to process Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Cross post [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/188629/how-to-use-push_back/)

---

I can use it normally like

```
Mat mat = (Mat_<uchar>(2, 4) << 5, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1, 9, 9);
Mat mat2 = (Mat_<uchar>(2, 4) << 5, 77, 0, 4, 2, 3, 9, 6);
//success
mat.push_back(mat2);
```

But I note there are other two usage when I use `F12` to see the definition. Such as

[image]

I think it supports `push_back` a `vector` into `Mat`, but I can not run it normally

```
//fail
vector<vector<uchar>> v1 = { { 5, 77, 0, 4 },{ 2, 3, 9, 6 } };
mat.push_back(v1);
//fail
vector<uchar> v2 = { 2, 3, 9, 6 };
mat.push_back(v2);
```

Can anybody tell me something? What have I missed something?

Comment: `push_back(const Mat& m)` is what you're using in your working example

Comment: In your fail case, you are calling push_back with a pointer but reference expected.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Is it not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guCmx.png)?

Comment: @nayab Sorry, I cannot understand your comment. Would you mind to post an answer to specfiy it?

Comment: push_back  for Mats with vectors does exist, but it is not documented. I would've expected, that it assumes the Mat to be with 1 col only, since converting a vector to Mat like cv::Mat a = cv::Mat(vector) will generate a Nx1 matrix with N rows, but my tests didn't work, it always tells that either type or cols is wrong. Probably you'd have to debug it by watching the code yourself and maybe adding debug code in openCV.